# W3C Validation and code in website text

Tags: validation, xhtml, markup

If I were to take the error logs of a file, and put them on a properly formatted HTML page, the page might not pass validation by W3C's validation tool because the error text contains markup that the validation tool gets confused with. How can I properly mark such text such that the validation tool realizes that it's reading what should be interpreted as a normal string and not markup?

Comment: What does the text from the error log look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the following characters into their HTML entities (stolen from the PHP manual on [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)):

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' 
''' (single quote) becomes '&#039;' 
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

Comment: The quotes are safe to use outside tags.

Comment: @Michas true, but in the context of arbitrary data coming from a log file entitying them is probably the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a normal string, then you should represent the characters that have special meaning in HTML with their respective entities. `<` to `&lt;` etc.

This will, of course, cause browsers to render those characters as text and not tags.

If you want browsers to render them as tags, then they aren't a normal string and they are a validity error.